# Why is the focus in Keras that much on weights?

Tags: keras

I was wondering, when reading up on `model.save()` and `model.load_weights()` (and its callback variant `ModelCheckpoint`), why the focus is that heavily on weights. I would have expected them to be in the same league as biases, but they hardly get mentioned. The only way to save them as well is to set `save_weights_only` to false, which would save the entire model. Why is this the case? What are the benefits of only saving the weights?

I am asking this because I am working on Physics-Informed-Neural-Networks, and would like to swap out certain loss functions, which requires me to transfer the weights of one model to another (Something like transfer learning). The results I am getting are not bad, but I am not sure if saving the biases as well would improve its performance.

Comment: The term weights in Keras already includes the biases.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy) has pointed out the "term weights in Keras already includes the biases".